# XSLT: change an attribute value if another attributes match

Tags: xml, xslt

PLease help, I'm new to XSLT, so I'm sorry for stupid questions.

I need a way to copy the data from corresponding /Actor/Context/ID/card/@val to /Actor/Relative/SecPlace/@val when /Actor/Relative/Place/@adj = /Actor/Context/ID/@account

I came up with this script but it only changes the value from /Actor/Relative/Place/@adj, not @val. Your help is really appreciated.

**XML:**

```
<Actor>
    <Relative>
        <Place adj="12345"/>
        <SecPlace zok="abc"/>
    </Relative>
    <Context>
        <ID account="54321">
            <Card val="abb"/>
        </ID>
        <ID account="12345">
            <Card val="def"/>
       </ID>
    </Context>
</Actor>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:param name="id-to-change" select="/Actor/Context/ID/@account"/>
<xsl:param name="new-name" select="/Actor/Context/ID/Card/"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@adj">
  <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test=". = $id-to-change">
        <xsl:attribute name="adj">
           <xsl:value-of select="$new-name"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy />
     </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a key to look up the `ID` elements by their `account` attribute

```
<xsl:key name="Context" match="Context/ID" use="@account" />
```

You say you want to copy an attribute to the `SecPlace` element, in which case you should have a template that matches a `SecPlace`, but you can add a condition to only match one where associated `Place` element has a matching `Context/ID` (which is checked using the key)

```
<xsl:template match="Relative[key('Context', Place/@adj)]/SecPlace">
```

Then, you can use the key to copy that attribute

```
<xsl:copy-of select="key('Context', ../Place/@adj)/Card/@val" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="Context" match="Context/ID" use="@account"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Relative[key('Context', Place/@adj)]/SecPlace">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="key('Context', ../Place/@adj)/Card/@val"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And it wasn't a stupid question. Indeed, you've made a good start by using the identity template in your XSLT.

EDIT: In answer to you comment, if you actually want to replace the value of the `zok` attribute, change the second template to match this attribute (instead of matching the parent `SecPlace` element, and then replace with a new attribute with the updated value

```
<xsl:template match="Relative[key('Context', Place/@adj)]/SecPlace/@zok">
    <xsl:attribute name="zok">
        <xsl:value-of select="key('Context', ../../Place/@adj)/Card/@val"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you Tim C - it is almost what I was looking for except for one little detail. After your XSLT the changed part of XML looks like <SecPlace val="def" zok="abc"/> and I needed <SecPlace zok="def"/>. Any ideas how to fix it? And thanks again for your help and warm words.

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer to show how you do this. You just match the existing `zok` attribute instead of the `SecPlace` element, and just replace the attribute with another. For future reference, if you do ever have to ask any more questions on SO, it's often useful to show your expected output, to remove any potential misunderstandings. Thanks!